# PrestaShop CMS page if condition

Tags: if-statement, content-management-system, prestashop

I am WordPress developer past 3 years. Now I'm started PrestaShop first project.
It's possible if conditions for cms pages?

For example:

```
If (cms page1) {
......
}
elseif (cms page2) {
...
}
else {
.....
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the template cms.tpl you can use the following syntax:

```
{if $cms->link_rewrite eq 'about-us'}
...
{else if $cms->link_rewrite eq 'bbb'}
...
{else}
...
{/if}
```

You can use as well directly the id: $cms->id